# Calling a java class in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab

When calling my java class from matlab, I'm getting " No main method with appropriate signature exists in Java class XXX" error. When I call the class from eclipse, for example, it is working fine.

My java code is similar to [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Network/0050__Java_Network_UDP_Multicast.htm) one (I've made some change so that IP port would be from user input).

Any suggestions how to solve it?

Executing "Hello World" don't provide me such error.

Please suggest what could be done.

Matlab R14 SP3,
Matlab code for calling the java class:

```
o=javaObject('XXX');
javaMethod('main','o', port, ip)     <== for my problematic class
javaMethod('main','o')               <== for the HelloWorld class
```

Comment: You need to pass a String array to the main method

Comment: this is how main is defined: `public static void main(String[] args)` and the actual call is `javaMethod('main','o', '2000', '225.225.225.225')`

Comment: What cricket_007 is saying is that you call the `main` method of class `o` with two arguments, while it is expecting one argument, which should be a `String[]`. So either you should call it like `javaMethod('main','o', {'2000', '225.225.225.225'})` or you change the signature of main to `main(String... args)` to mathc the signature - (the 1st option should be the preferred).

Comment: Thank you.I'll use the 1st option